# How to calculate the "vortex" correlation function in 2D free system?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, correlation-functions, vortex, duality

I want to calculate the following correlation function in 2D square lattice:
$$G(i, j, \tau) \equiv\left\langle e^{-\frac{i}{2}\left[\hat{\Phi}_{i}(\tau)-\hat{\Phi}_{j}(0)\right]}\right\rangle_{0}$$
$\hat{\Phi}_{i}(\tau)$ here is something like "vortex operator":
$$\hat{\Phi}_{i}=\sum_{l \neq i} \theta_{i}(l) \hat{n}_{l}$$
where $ \theta_{i}(l)$ is the angle from site $i$ to site $j$, and $ \hat{n}$ is the particle number operator. Note that the $\left\langle\right\rangle_{0}$ means the Hamiltonian is free, i.e. be quadratic: $H[b^\dagger,b]$.

Firstly, since $\left\langle \hat{\Phi}_{i}(\tau)\hat{\Phi}_{j}(0)\right\rangle_{0}$ is easy to be obtained, I try to expand correlation function by Taylor expansion, and then calculate expectation order by order, i.e. $$\left\langle e^{\lambda \hat{A}}\right\rangle=1+\lambda\langle\hat{A}\rangle+\frac{1}{2 !} \lambda^{2}\left\langle\hat{A}^{2}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{3 !} \lambda^{3}\left\langle\hat{A}^{3}\right\rangle+\cdots$$
where $\hat{A}$ is just  $[\hat{\Phi}_{i}(\tau)-\hat{\Phi}_{j}(0)]$. However, I do not believe the result is controlable since $[\hat{\Phi}_{i}(\tau)-\hat{\Phi}_{j}(0)]^n$ is not necessarily small enough.

As the result, I want to try **duality** method, but I don't know the details of it. I want to ask that can I calculate it by duality? Could anyone give me some suggestions (or other methods) or reference? Thanks!

Comment: Cumulant expansion may do the trick - i.e., expanding the logarithm of the average. This is equivalent to expanding free energy rather than partition function in thermodynamics.

Comment: @Vadim Thanks for your comments! I also try cumulant expansion, but I still suspect its controllability in my case since $\left[\hat{\Phi}_{i}(\tau)-\hat{\Phi}_{j}(0)\right]$ here is something like "vortex", i.e. summation of phase, so that it may be large enough to truncation at low order.